# Which of these would be public functions and which would be private

Tags: javascript

This the is the code

```js
function MakeComponent(iStockId, iQty, iPrice) {
  var comp = document.createElement("div");
  comp.stockId = iStockId;
  var qty = iQty;
  var price = iPrice;
  comp.sPrice = function(newPrice) {
    price = newPrice;
    show();
  };
  comp.sStockId = function(newId) {
    comp.stockId = newId;
    show();
  };

  function sQty(newQty) {
    qty = newQty;
    show();
  }
  comp.calc = function() {
    return qty * price;
  };

  function show() {
    comp.innerHTML = label();
  }
  var label = function() {
    return "id:" + comp.stockId + " qty:" + qty + " price: $" + price;
  };
  comp.print = function() {
    console.log(label());
  };
  show();
  return comp;
}
```

If anyone can help that would be awesome.  From what I have researched print, calc, sStockID, sPrice, and im not sure about var label.

Comment: Everything that's a property of `comp` is a public function. Everything else is private.

Comment: Think about which functions are exposed and which ones aren’t. Can you access `label` outside of `MakeComponent`?

Comment: would label be considered a private function then